# How to toggle an Accordion Component with a Button outside of the Accordion element?

Tags: reactjs, button, toggle, accordion, semantic-ui

I am trying to build a button that toggles an accordion component when clicked. The button exists on a separate part of the page from the area the Accordion expands, however I still want to toggle the accordion with said button.

As I have created a separate Accordion.js file for the component, I have tried writing onClick={Accordion.handleClick} on the PostCard.js file. The "handleClick" function is currently the onClick that triggers the Accordion in Accordion.js, however I now want to change that action from where it is currently, to the new toggle button.

Accordion.js - where the Accordion and handleClick currently work:

```
    state = { activeIndex: 0 }

      handleClick = (e, titleProps) => {
        const { index } = titleProps
        const { activeIndex } = this.state
        const newIndex = activeIndex === index ? -1 : index

        this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex })
      }

      render() {
        const { activeIndex } = this.state

        return (
          <Accordion>
            <Accordion.Title active={activeIndex === -1} index={0} onClick= . 
  {this.handleClick}>
              <Icon name='dropdown'/>
            </Accordion.Title>
            <Accordion.Content active={activeIndex === -1}>
            <Card.Content>
              <ProgressBar />
            </Card.Content>
            </Accordion.Content>
          </Accordion>
        )
      }
    }
```

PostCard.js - where the button I wish to toggle lives:

```
  <Button floated="right" onClick={<AccordionDropDown />}>
    <Icon name="angle down" style={{ margin: 0 }}></Icon>
  </Button>
```

and the section in which the Accordion is displayed within a Card:

```
 <Card.Content>
    <AccordionDropDown />
  </Card.Content>
```

Expected: Clicking the Button will toggle the Accordion field to display

Actual: The only way to display the Accordion field is from clicking the current Accordion Title icon.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the ref for that function:

Edit:
I forgot that toggleAccordion is not defined till components mounts.
Here is a more complete example.

Accordion js

```
class Accordion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opened: false,
    };
    // The actual function
    this.handleToggle = this.handleToggle.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { setRef } = this.props;
    // Sending 'this' as argument to access class methods
    setRef(this);
  }

  // Function that needs to be called
  handleToggle() {
    const { opened } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      opened: !opened,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { className, children, title } = this.props;
    const { opened } = this.state;
    const openClass = opened ? 'open' : '';
    return (
      <div className={`accordion ${className}`}>
        <div className="accordion-title">
          <button
            className={`accordion-btn ${openClass}`}
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleToggle}
          >
            {title}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className={`accordion-content ${openClass}`}>
          {children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Container js
This will get the reference from the accordion component

```
class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (this.accordion) {
      // Calling the needed function
      this.accordion.handleToggle();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { className } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <Card.Content>
          // Here we set the reference to accordion component
          <AccordionDropDown setRef={(el) => { this.accordion = el; }} />
        </Card.Content>
        <Button floated="right" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <Icon name="angle down" style={{ margin: 0 }}></Icon>
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this response. When adding in the Accordion.js code you wrote, I receive 11 errors and "setToggle is not a function". Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: @JakeDewar setToggle must be a prop with a function that receives another function or an object. I edited the code with a more complete example. :)

Answer (score 0):

try `Accordion.Toggle`

```js
export function ExampleCustomToggle() {
    return (
        <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">Click me!</Accordion.Toggle>
                </Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
                    <Card.Body>Hello! I'm the body</Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
            <Card>
                <Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Toggle eventKey="1">Click me!</Accordion.Toggle>
                </Card.Header>
                <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="1">
                    <Card.Body>Hello! I'm another body</Card.Body>
                </Accordion.Collapse>
            </Card>
        </Accordion>
    );
}
```